# UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY node.js doesn't work with npm update

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

```
C:\Users\Projects\webapp
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@15.4.2
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY webpack@1.14.0

npm ERR! peer dep missing: react@~0.13.0, required by react-anything-sortable@0.4.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: react@>=0.12.1 <0.14, required by react-tagged-input@0.0.17
npm ERR! peer dep missing: webpack@^2.2.0, required by webpack-dev-server@2.3.0
npm ERR! code 1
```

I have above error and don't know how to fix. Tried npm update webpack react but it didn't resolve the issue. Although my app is running fine but it's better to fix it before we have bigger messes.

Comment: check this
https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a fresh install

```
rm -rf node_modules/
npm cache clean
npm install
```